88. Merge Sorted Array
The task is:
here
i've successfuly got working code on local machine, also on platform first three casess attempted my solution. But if i run Submit i've get the undefined behavior runtime error on this case:
nums1 = [2,0], m = 1, nums2 = [1], n = 1. As i understand in result must be nums1 = [1,2] and i've get it in local machine without any errors. why that happen?
class Solution {
public:
    void merge(std::vector<int>& nums1, int m, std::vector<int>& nums2, int n);
};

void Solution::merge(std::vector<int>& nums1, int m, std::vector<int>& nums2, int n)
{
    int iNums1 = m - 1;
    int iNums2 = n - 1;
    int iResult = m + n - 1;

    for (; iResult >= 0 && iNums2 >= 0; iResult--)
    {
        if (iNums2 < 0)
        {
            break;;
        }
        else if (iNums1 < 0 && iNums2 >= 0)
        {
            std::swap(nums2, nums1);
            break;
        }       
        else if (nums2[iNums2] > nums1[iNums1])
        {
            nums1[iResult] = nums2[iNums2--];
        }
        else if (iResult <= m && nums1[iResult - 1] <= nums2[iNums2] && nums1[iResult] > nums2[iNums2])
        {
            nums1[iResult + 1] = nums1[iResult];
            nums1[iResult] = nums2[iNums2--];
        }
    }
}

used testcase on local machine, no errors occured:
Solution s;
std::vector<int> nums1 = { 2, 0 };
std::vector<int> nums2 = { 1 };
std::vector<int> result = { 1, 2 };
s.merge(nums1, 1, nums2, 1);




heap buffer overflow on nums1[iResult - 1]

Replace al your [i] with .at(i) and then debug your code.  You should know C++ is not going to prevent you from accessing memory you shouldn't but it will be undefined behavior.

Yep, changed access to element from operator[] to 'at' method and got this UB in line else if (iResult <= m && nums1.at(iResult - 1) <= nums2.at(iNums2) && nums1.at(iResult) > nums2.at(iNums2))
Thanks, must to think about that.

You can't observe the absence of undefined behaviour. Its nastiest manifestation is when a program seems to work.

You need to add compiler options to enable sanitizers on your local machine to reproduce UB reports from LeetCode.

Best solution is to use std::merge and merge things in reversed order (note r suffix for iterator functions).
This way merge can be done in place without overriding the input data.
class Solution {
public:
    void merge(vector<int>& nums1, int m, vector<int>& nums2, int n) {
        std::merge(
            nums1.rbegin() + nums1.size() - m, nums1.rend(), 
            nums2.rbegin() + nums2.size() - n, nums2.rend(), 
            nums1.rbegin(),
            std::greater<>{});
    }
};

Live demo

This can be simplified to std::merge(nums1.rbegin() + n, nums1.rend(), nums2.rbegin(), nums2.rend(), nums1.rbegin(), std::greater<>{});

Outstanding! This had me talking to myself, saying, "Why didn't I think of that?" You got my up-vote, for sure.

@Marek-R, The best of!

@Unmitigated, but it slow by runtime on leetcode.

@АлександрМаксаков Runtime can vary greatly even for the exact same code on LeetCode, so that isn't something important to consider.

Swapping nums1 and nums2 does not make sense as the result is supposed to be entirely stored inside nums1.
Additionally, the last condition is not needed; if the next element to add to the output is not from the first vector, then it must necessarily be from the second one. What remains to be checked is the bounds: if there are no elements left in the first vector, we can only take elements from the second one and vice versa.
for (; iResult >= 0 && iNums2 >= 0; iResult--) {      
    if (iNums1 < 0 || iNums2 >= 0 && nums2[iNums2] > nums1[iNums1]){
        nums1[iResult] = nums2[iNums2--];
    } else {
        nums1[iResult] = nums1[iNums1--];
    }
}


This solution getting segfault on testcase:
   std::vector<int> nums1;
    std::vector<int> nums2 = { 1 };
    std::vector<int> result = { 1 };
    s.merge(nums1, 0, nums2, 1);


about swapping, it works for that case where segfault happend.

@АлександрМаксаков That's not even a valid test case. nums1 must have size equal to n + m. Just try submitting it on LeetCode.

strange but fact - on the leetcode it works O.o and submitted

yep, nums1 in case mut be { 0 }; e.g nums1.size() = 1;

Annotated Solution
The source code below is taken from the OP. I have added copious comments explaining just what went wrong.
I use #if-else-endif preprocessor statements to isolate the bad code, and insert my corrections. That means you can copy-and-paste this back into the the orginal program, and it should work. Of course, it will be a lot prettier once you have cleaned it up.
void Solution::merge(std::vector<int>& nums1, int m, std::vector<int>& nums2, int n)
{
    int iNums1 = m - 1;
    int iNums2 = n - 1;
    int iResult = m + n - 1;

#if 0
    // This loop will stop early when `iNums1 >= 0 && iNums2 < 0`.
    for (; iResult >= 0 && iNums2 >= 0; iResult--)
    {
#else
    // If `iResult` is not negative, then you KNOW that either 
    // `iNums1` or `iNums2` (or both) are also non-negative.
    // So, keep looping!
    for (; iResult >= 0; iResult--)
    {
#endif
        if (iNums2 < 0)
        {
            // This is perfect. Note, however, when you had the wrong 
            // termination condition on the for-statement, this was, 
            // effectively, a "no-op." That's because `iNums2` could 
            // never be negative.
            break;;
        }
#if 0
        // There is nothing wrong with this test: the program will work 
        // fine if you leave it as it is. The second test, however, is 
        // redundant. We already know that `iNums2` in not negative.
        // We just tested it!
        else if (iNums1 < 0 && iNums2 >= 0)
#else
        else if (iNums1 < 0)
#endif
        {
#if 0
            // Swapping vectors is the wrong idea.
            // You will lose the data already present in `nums1`.
            std::swap(nums2, nums1);
            break;
#else
            // When `iNums1` goes negative, you can simply copy 
            // whatever remains in `nums2`.
            while (iResult >= 0) {
                nums1[iResult--] = nums2[iNums2--];
            }
            break;
#endif
        }
        else if (nums2[iNums2] > nums1[iNums1])
        {
            nums1[iResult] = nums2[iNums2--];
        }
#if 0
        // You are working too hard here. 
        else if (iResult <= m 
            && nums1[iResult - 1] <= nums2[iNums2] 
            && nums1[iResult] > nums2[iNums2])
        {
            nums1[iResult + 1] = nums1[iResult];
            nums1[iResult] = nums2[iNums2--];
        }
#else
        else
        {
            // Since we know that `nums2[iNums2] > nums1[iNums1]` 
            // is false (because we just tested it), then 
            // `nums1[iNums1]` must be the one that goes in the 
            // result.
            nums1[iResult] = nums1[iNums1--];
        }
#endif
    }
}

A framework for solving LeetCode problems
I use the same "framework" for all of the LeetCode problems.
It starts with function main, a simple driver that let's me add as many examples as I want. I began with the three examples from the LeetCode website. Then, I added the failed test from the OP, and the inevitable (and, dare I say, pathological) boundary test, where both vectors are emtpy.
int main()
{
    std::cout << "LeetCode 88. Merge Sorted Array"
        "\nhttps://leetcode.com/problems/permutations-ii/"
        "\n\n";
    solve("Example 1", { 1,2,3,0,0,0 }, 3, { 2,5,6 }, 3);
    solve("Example 2", { 1 }, 1, {}, 0);
    solve("Example 3", { 0 }, 0, { 1 }, 1);
    solve("Example 4", { 2,0 }, 1, { 1 }, 1);
    solve("Example 5", {}, 0, {}, 0);
}

Function solve stages the solution, and displays the results in the same way that examples are shown on the LeetCode website.
I use by-value parameters for the vectors that are passed in. That way, the arguments used in function main can be braced initializer lists.
void solve(
    std::string_view heading,
    std::vector<int> nums1,
    int const m,
    std::vector<int> nums2,
    int const n)
{
    std::cout
        << heading
        << "\n"
        << "\n  Input: nums1 = " << put_vector(nums1)
        << ", m = " << m
        << ", nums2 = " << put_vector(nums2)
        << ", n = " << n;
    Solution{}.merge(nums1, m, nums2, n);
    std::cout
        << "\n  Output: " << put_vector(nums1)
        << "\n\n";
}

A small set of tools gets used over and over. This time out, it was class template put_vector, which is implemented in the style of an I/O manipulator.
Other tools I have include helpers for the horrible linked lists and binary trees favored by LeetCode.
template< typename T >
class put_vector
{
    std::vector<T> const& v;
public:
    put_vector(std::vector<T> const& v) : v{ v } {}
private:
    void put(std::ostream& ost) const {
        ost.put('[');
        if (!v.empty()) {
            ost << v.front();
            for (std::size_t i{ 1u }; i < v.size(); ++i) {
                ost << ',' << v[i];
            }
        }
        ost.put(']');
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ost, put_vector const& pv) {
        pv.put(ost);
        return ost;
    }
};

Now, all I have to do is plug in the solution. I always start with a stub.
// This using declaration allows the LeetCode Solution 
// to be used without modifying its function signature.
// 
// (Shame on you, LeetCode, for teaching programmers to 
// rely on `using namespace std;`.)
using std::vector;

class Solution {
public:
    void merge(vector<int>& nums1, int m, vector<int>& nums2, int n) {
    }
};

Because I can copy all the boilerplate from prior LeetCode solutions, it only takes about 5-10 minutes, for these preliminaries. Then, I can run the program.
LeetCode 88. Merge Sorted Array
https://leetcode.com/problems/permutations-ii/

Example 1

  Input: nums1 = [1,2,3,0,0,0], m = 3, nums2 = [2,5,6], n = 3
  Output: [1,2,3,0,0,0]

Example 2

  Input: nums1 = [1], m = 1, nums2 = [], n = 0
  Output: [1]

Example 3

  Input: nums1 = [0], m = 0, nums2 = [1], n = 1
  Output: [0]

Example 4

  Input: nums1 = [2,0], m = 1, nums2 = [1], n = 1
  Output: [2,0]

Example 5

  Input: nums1 = [], m = 0, nums2 = [], n = 0
  Output: []

Now, the fun begins...

thanks, it might be more useful then my testCase() funcs)
